# Create Data frame with different number of columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a text file like below, I wanna create a data frame, and when I read this file using pyspark I get only three columns of the data frame like below (second image). could someone help me to create a data frame with different number columns in each row

123, 45, 56 
123, 45 ,56, 2022/06/15, 56.78 
123, 45, 56 , 2022/06/15, 56, 566, 7890 
123, 45, 56 , , 56, , 7890 
123, ,56,78

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Share your code, so that a community may help

Comment: Pandas doesn't support different number of columns per row. All rows must have the maximum number of columns (but values can be Null)

Comment: dataframes are 2D arrays so rows and columns have to be consistent (you can't have different numbers of rows for each column, or different numbers of columns for each row). however you can use nulls or empty strings if the underlying data isn't 2D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in Spark or pandas, because they are two-dimensional dataframes with a fixed number of rows and columns. So, you **must** have an equal number of rows for each column and also an equal number of columns for each row.